# How to speed up jQuery for events on many elements

Tags: jquery

I'm using the following jQuery code to highlight the row the mouse is over:

```
$("#rpt tr:has(td):not(.noHighlight)").hover(
    function() { $(this).css("background-color", "Silver"); },
    function() { $(this).css("background-color", "Transparent"); }
);
```

When I start getting more than 500 rows, there is a noticeable delay, as the color is about 1/2 second behind the cursor. For very long tables, this causes IE to offer to stop the script as it takes a long time to render.

Is there a better/faster way to achieve this affect that can handle a large number of rows?

Comment: Well firstly, take a look at @Crayon Violent's answer. Second, could you not use pure CSS to give each row a hover effect? EDIT: See @IngernalBadger's answer.

Answer (score 3):

If you can add a .highlight class onto the rows you want to highlight you can just use css like this:

```
tr.highlight {
    background-color: blue;
}

tr.highlight:hover
{
    background-color : red;
}
```

Comment: Bah, got there before me... +1

Comment: No IE6, if anybody cares at all :). Still, I'd say if you can solve it with CSS, you don't need jQuery.

Comment: Duh, over-engineering as usual. :)  However, when I do this, I still see the delay. Is that just the browser having to deal with such a large page, and there's nothing I can do about it?

Comment: I didn't test it with that many rows (2 infact, lol). But I guess it is just slowing the browser down too much having that much content. Is it at least faster than the jQuery method?

Comment: If you deal with so may table rows, you cannot really do anything about it. There will always be a limit where the browser will start to become slower. With IE, it happens earlier, with Chrome, later, but it happens :).

Answer (score 1):

500 rows on a page is a bit much for a user to digest a time. I suggest solving this by making use of pagination (only showing the list a little bit at a time)

Comment: Unfortunately it's a user requirement to show a large number of rows, though I agree that's one way to prevent it.

Comment: I think that depends on context.  If it's some kind of data management tool with an editable table then it's not really a problem.

Comment: Well even with a data management tool..yes, a user can easily find themselves in a situation of wanting to *make changes* to 500 rows at a time, but to actually *present* and *look* at 500 rows at a time? That's not easy to digest and just begs for errors in judgment to be made if it's based on eyeballing large sets of data like that.

Answer (score 0):

If the color changing slowness is caused by jQuery searching for what to do, then this will help.  Right now you are using jQuery("#") ID selector, that's awesome.  On a large page/dom, you can go a step farther and you can tell limit jQuery's DOM searching explicitly like this:

```
jQuery("tr:has(td):not(.noHighlight)","#rpt").hover(
    function() { $(this).css("background-color", "Silver"); },
    function() { $(this).css("background-color", "Transparent"); }
);
```

Right now, you're searching the entire dom for "#rpt". the second parameter explicity tells jQuery to start searching the dom within the second parameter only.

Comment: @gfrizzle fyi, only try my solution if infernalbadger's solution does not fit